# Typical application for FAN5333B

Tags: led-driver

I have an issue regarding the typical application for [FAN5333B LED driver](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/FAN5333.pdf).

According to the spec, SW output can achieve 30V to GND. 
Can this influence the input voltage which is typically about 5V ? Both point are directly connected for DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FAN5333B is a [boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter).

[image: boost converter]

It pulsates current trough the SW pin and uses the magnetic field in the inductor when SW is off to boost the voltage. It specifies a typical Vout of 30V, which is after the diode. The switch pin is allowed to go up to 35V, which it will. Since the SW voltage will pulsate.

This does not have an effect on Vin, except that the circuit draws high current in short pulses.
It has a 1.5MHz Switching Frequency, which requires tight board design.

*ps: if you have not used buck or boost converters before, I suggest using a lower frequency to increase your success.*

Comment: hopefully it would mostly run in continuous current mode and not draw short pulses at the input. - see startup graph on datasheet page 6

Comment: @Jasen That is the effect of the input capacitors. Is has to keep switching, otherwise Vout will be Vin.

Comment: @Jeroen3 thanks for the answer but  Vin and SW are connected physically  in one point. how is that possible for the voltage to be 5V and 30V at the same point? Inductance has extremely low resistance to DC.

Comment: @hanni76 When the FET inside SW shorts it to ground, current flows trough the inductor. When the FET opens, the current in the inductor continues flowing, since (very simply put) inductors resist change in current. This current goes to the diode and the load. Ohms law of current and load resistance defines the voltage. This is how boost converters work.

Comment: @Jeroen3 continuous current mode does not preclude switching, it just means the switch closes before current stops flowing in the inductor

Comment: Consider a premade switch mode power supply module or a lower frequency controller, since it seems like you're new to this I fear you will not be successful implementing this chip.